# Embed code that tracks clicks on certain DOM elements (issue is on links/buttons that redirect)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Let's say I have an embed code with a script that adds events to certain DOM elements. These would normally be links or buttons. Once an event is called I do an ajax call to record that click event.

The problems comes in with links that redirect. So, adding an onclick event to an

```
<a href="http://google.com">link</a>
```

might not work since the page will be redirected before the event is recorded via the ajax call.

Obviously sites like Google Analytics, Omniture do this when they track conversions. Are there any good ways to solve this problem?

Also, assume this all works with an embed code (just like Google Analytics) - so we can't modify the html code too much.

And in case the ajax call fails, the page still has to get redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hijack the click, prevent the default then trigger the redirect on the callback.

var link = '';
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  link = $(this).attr("href");
  $.ajax( .... function () {
     window.location = link;
  })
});

Comment: Yea, that's probably what we'll end up doing - but will also need to detect if the href is javascript:function() or a javascript:void(0). Just wondered if there was a better way. The embed code will be on our users' sites and I don't like messing with other sites' HTML.

Comment: This is an old question but for the benefit of new readers, you could theoretically test if the link starts with "javascript:" and run eval() instead of assigning window.location